# Always publish website with release code?

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, publish

Is it possible to change some setting so that Visual Studio always use the "release" configuration when publishing?

I use debug mode when i develop to clear some caches and stuff like that and i also have different web.configs for release and debug. Sometimes when i publish i forget to change the configuration to release and i end up with a broken website ;)

I understand i can do this with MS Build or something but publish working fine except for this. Any tips?

Comment: For some reason, VS 2010 always uses the Debug build when I use "Publish Web Site"; if I can figure out how to stop that (since the web site has no project, but instead has options only in the solution), maybe I can answer this question, or vice versa...

Comment: @Stuck if this answered helped you please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

1. In Solution Explorer, select the project.
2. On the View menu, click Property Pages.
3. Click the Build or Debug tab, in a Visual C# or a Visual F# project, the Compile or Debug tab, in a Visual Basic project, or Configuration Properties, in a Visual C++ project.
4. In the Configuration drop-down list, click Debug or Release."

Steps provided by:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx0123s5.aspx

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. It's not about how to change configuration, but rather having a specific configuration when *publishing*, which is not equal to *compiling*.

Answer (score 0):

As of at least VS 2017, the web publish settings now include a setting for which configuration to publish, which defaults to Release, so you can publish the release build even when VS is still in Debug configuration.

I just wish that they had also done this for regular Click-Once applications as well...